# How to make a bot click the download button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]
I'm making a bot, however, it doesn't click the download button at the end of the site. It was for him to click and generate a PDF report, but it doesn't work

I've done it, but it doesn't work

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inibe"]/font]').click()
```

In this HTML code is the href

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/a/font').click()
```

This is what the mouse selector points to. But anyway, it doesn't work, it returns an error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the text of the error and the HTML code of the button?

Comment: What error message you are getting? Share the HTML of the table row element.

Comment: show in question minimal working code with real URL so we could run it. And put in question full error message.

Comment: In [1]: browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inibe"]/font').click()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3ca2cabeeb2b> in <module>
----> 1 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inibe"]/font').click()

Comment: --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="inibe"]/font"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)

Comment: I can't send the URL for testing because I need to log into a customer's profile